# How to colorize a datepicker?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How to mark 8 days in a green, 2 orange datepicker and do this action until the end of the year?
Starting from a date that is in the database.
I attach an image.
I already asked but did not explain me well.

[image]

At the moment I have the following code:

```
if (Tipo == "1") //Tipos de Jornadas
                    {
                        DateTime FechaJornada = Convert.ToDateTime(iRow["Jornada_Ini"]);
                        DateTime FechaJ = FechaJornada.AddDays(8);
                        DateTime Descanso = FechaJ.AddDays(2);
                        DateTime Jornada2 = FechaJ.AddDays(2);
                        DateTime Fecha2 = Jornada2.AddDays(8);
                        DateTime Descanso2 = Fecha2.AddDays(2);
                        DateTime Jornada3 = Fecha2.AddDays(2);
                        DateTime Fecha3 = Jornada3.AddDays(8);
                        DateTime Descanso3 = Fecha3.AddDays(2);  

                        if (e.Day.Date >= FechaJornada && e.Day.Date < FechaJ) //Días Laboraes
                        {
                            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
                        }
                        if (e.Day.Date >= Jornada2 && e.Day.Date < Fecha2) //Días Laboraes
                        {
                            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
                        }
                        if (e.Day.Date >= Jornada3 && e.Day.Date < Fecha3) //Días Laboraes
                        {
                            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
                        }
                        if (e.Day.Date >= FechaJ && e.Day.Date < Descanso) //Días Descanso
                        {
                            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
                        }
                        if (e.Day.Date >= Fecha2 && e.Day.Date < Descanso2) //Días Descanso
                        {
                            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
                        }
                        if (e.Day.Date >= Fecha3 && e.Day.Date < Descanso3) //Días Descanso
                        {
                            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
                        }
                    }
```

But I want to do it in a Cycle since I have to fill the calendar according to the type of Journey you have. At the moment I want to paint the calendar 8 days in green and 2 in orange until the end of the month and start the new month with the color in which I stayed in the previous month.
You can do this with a cycle, you can support me to know

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DayRender` event handler for such manipulation. Although my answer doesn't fully address your problem but It can give you an hint to continue of how you can do this by adding a little bit logic because days of every month are not equal i.e. some have 30 days, some have 28/29 or 31, it requires little bit thinking of how you can achieve this.

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
 int[] arOfDaysInOrange = { 9, 10, 19, 20, 29, 30 };
 if (arOfDaysInOrange.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(e.Day.DayNumberText)))
  e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
 else
  e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
}
```

Output of this code snipped is this:

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @M Adeel Khalid, here I see that the fixed days of rest are shown, and what I want is that they are not fixed that are taken according to the date of the day that is in my database and after that date For 8 days On the ninth day I mark two in orange and start again with 8 greens and 2 oranges